# On the higher-dimensional Berry-Robbins problem

Tags: group-actions, flag-varieties, configuration-spaces, equivariant

Let $C_n(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denote the configuration space of $n$ distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, say $\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n$. The symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ acts on $C_n(\mathbb{R}^d)$ via
$$\sigma.(\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n) = (\mathbf{x}_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}),$$
where $\sigma \in \Sigma_n$. Moreover, $\sigma \in \Sigma_n$ acts on $[A] \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})/U(1)^n$, where $A = (a_1,\ldots, a_n) \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, via
$$\sigma.[A] = [a_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}, \ldots, a_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}],$$
where $a_j$ is the $j$-th column of $A$ ($1 \leq j \leq n$) and $[A]$ represents the equivalence class of $A$ under $\sim$, where $A_1 \sim A_2$ iff each column of $A_2$ is equal to the corresponding column of $A_1$ times a phase factor.

Problem: for which pairs of integers $(n,d)$, with $n \geq 2$ and $d \geq 1$, does there exist a smooth map $f_{n,d}: C_n(\mathbb{R}^d) \to GL(n,\mathbb{C})/U(1)^n$ which is $\Sigma_n$-equivariant?

Note that for $d = 3$, this is essentially the Berry-Robbins problem, which is known to have a positive solution by the work of Atiyah and Bielawski.

I was always puzzled by the restriction $d = 3$. What happens when $d > 3$? Are there some obstructions to the existence of such a map for some $n$'s, given a specific $d > 3$?

Edit: I think there are obstructions for $n = 2$, for some values of $d$, because the existence of such a smooth $\Sigma_2$-equivariant map seems more or less equivalent to the existence of a smooth map from $f: S^{d-1} \to S^2$ with the property that $f(-v) = -f(v)$. Aren't there obstructions to that in general, via the work of Borsuk, Ulam, Brouwer and others?